# Реализовать циклический сдвиг вправо на K разрядов

Tags: c++

Реализовать циклический сдвиг вправо на K разрядов.

Пример: K=2

00011010**10** => **10**00011010.

если не сложно, то с более менее понятными пояснениями, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем? Минимальные знания двоичной арифметики или гугления дадут вам искомый код. Более того, для Visual Studio есть специальные "функции", которые это реализуют.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, для какого представления битов вам нужен сдвиг? Это целое число, или цепочка битов произвольной длины, или что?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

примерно так

```
unsigned int x = 0x1234ABCD;
int k = 2;
x = (x >> k) | (x << (32 - k));
```

вместо 32 подставьте требуемое значение, если отличается

Comment: Вроде как человек просил с комментариями. А вот что такое 32? 32 бита? А если у него как в примере 10 бит? Ну, а например, возьмем простое 110 (6). После сдвига на 2 должно получиться 101 (5). А что получится в Вашем примере? Заминусовали человека. Отлично. Поздравляю. Так а где правильный ответ?

Comment: Двигать `int` вправо небезопасно и зависит от реализации. Чтобы эта формула работала, `x >> k` обязательно должно использовать логический сдвиг, а это ничем не гарантируется.

Comment: @ixSci внесу свои 2 копейки: а сдвиг влево отрицательного числа - вообще UB.

Comment: да, UB, добавил `unsigned`

Answer (score 2):

Читайте код и разбирайтесь:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int BYTE = 10; // количество разрядов
const unsigned int STEP = 2;  // на сколько шагов нужно будет сдвинуть

int main(){
    bitset<BYTE> bit(106), part1, part2, result;

    cout << "bit\t" << bit << endl; // исходное число

    // результат будет составлен из двух частей
    part1 = bit >> STEP; // первая часть, два сдвига вправо
    cout << "part1\t" << part1 << endl;

    part2 = bit << BYTE - STEP; // вторая часть, восемь сдвигов влево (десять разрядов числа минус два шага)
    cout << "part2\t" << part2 << endl;

    result = part1 | part2; // объеденияем части

    cout << "result\t"  << result << endl; // результат объединения частей

    return 0;
}
```

вывод:

[image: результат]

Answer (score 1):

[`std::vector<bool>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) + [`std::rotate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/) = [результат выполнения](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xRw5ITFlhOKdDiHC)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using BinVec = std::vector<bool>;

void print(const BinVec& v) 
{
    for(bool b : v) 
        std::cout << b;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void shr(BinVec& v, int k) 
{
    k %= v.size();
    std::rotate(v.begin(), v.end() - k, v.end());
}

int main() 
{
    BinVec v(8);
    v[0] = 1;

    print(v);
    shr(v, 2);
    print(v);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В С++ есть стандартная библиотека  для работы с битами. Код, созданный с ее помощью, наверное, не самый оптимальный, зато очень наглядный. [Пример реализации](http://ideone.com/47AXjX) со сдвигом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<10> baz ("0001101010"); // 10-количество бит в числе
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) // 2-на сколько бит сдвигаем
    {
        bool temp = baz[0];
        baz >>= 1; // >> - сдвиг вправо
        baz[baz.size()-1] = temp;
    }
    std::cout << baz;
}
```