# инвертировать P разрядов в булевом векторе начиная с разряда K

Tags: c++

Дано: Булевый вектор типа unsigned long, инвертировать P разрядов в булевом векторе начиная с разряда K;

Пример: P=3,K=1(нумерация с 0)

0**001**101010 => 0**110**101010

Comment: Приведите пример попыток, что именно не получилось?

Comment: Здесь за вас не будут решать всё домашнее задание, попытайтесь что-то сделать сами. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501146

Comment: ну, судя по этому и предыдущему вопросу - скучающие все же находятся)

Comment: @kroder, да, поиграться с битами - древнейшая забава программистов

Answer (score 3):

Если у Вас просто переменная типа `unsigned long`, то достаточно использовать операцию xor с маской:

```
int p = 3;
int k = 1;
unsigned long x = 0b0001101010;
unsigned long mask = (~0ul << k) ^ (~0ul << (k + p));
x = x ^ mask;
std::cout << std::bitset<8>(x) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

В С++ есть стандартная библиотека  для работы с битами. Код, созданный с ее помощью, наверное, не самый оптимальный, зато очень наглядный.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    int P=3,K=1;
    std::bitset<10> baz ("0001101010");
    for(int i=baz.size()-1-K; i>baz.size()-1-(K+P); i--)baz.flip(i);
    std::cout << baz;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, операция, которая инвертирует биты - xor с единичным битом. Значит, вам надо просто получить число из P единичных битов, выполнить сдвиг так, чтобы эти биты встали на нужное место - начиная с K, и выполнить xor для этих двух чисел.

С кодированием сами справитесь или нужна помощь?